# Firefox Portable Opens but Cannot navigate to URL using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium having the path in same location of the exe file. Open browser but can't  navigate to the url..

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = "FirefoxPortable/FirefoxPortable.exe";
    IWebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver(service);
    wd.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
```

Comment: firefox installed location ?

Comment: Firefox is fine. Is portable I'm giving just the file path and opens it